# Bloodline Mutation Swapping Point

Tags: pathfinder-1e, gestalt, bloodline

So, I have a wonderfully overpowered campaign I am taking part in, in which we have a level 20 gestalt pathfinder character.  I am making a bloodrager/sorcerer, both crossblooded abyssal and verdant bloodlines.  At level 15, the sorcerer bloodline powers for abyssal and verdant are both rather miserable, and I was wondering if I could swap this level 15 power for a bloodline mutation, given that there is this line:

> Whenever a bloodrager or a sorcerer gains a new bloodline power, she can swap her bloodline power for a bloodline mutation whose prerequisites she meets

Is this possible, or are bloodline mutations blocked in at 1st, 4th, and 9th levels for sorcerers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The current mutations are available only at their listed levels

The [Bloodline Mutation](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/bloodlines/bloodline-mutations/) was created specially to allow a more diverse customization of your sorcerer bloodline powers. The only restriction is that you must meet the prerequisites for that bloodline mutation:

> Although heirs to similar arcane bloodlines may share commonalities, the unique circumstances in which a bloodline enters a bloodrager or sorcerer’s lineage can result in the manifestation of particularly strange or unusual bloodline powers known as mutations. **Whenever a bloodrager or a sorcerer gains a new bloodline power, she can swap her bloodline power for a bloodline mutation whose prerequisites she meets**. Once this choice is made, it cannot be changed, and a bloodrager or sorcerer cannot swap a bloodline power that she has altered or replaced with an archetype for a bloodline mutation. A bloodrager need not be in a bloodrage to use her bloodline mutation powers. Alternatively, a bloodrager or sorcerer can select a bloodline mutation in place of a **bloodline bonus feat**, provided her **class level is at least equal to the level of the bloodline** ability the mutation normally replaces.

Also note that when replacing a bloodline bonus feat, you have a minimum level to replace, so that was certainly considered by the developers.

However, do note that the 3 published mutations have a more specific wording that does not allow you to replace a 15th level granted bloodline power:

> [Blood Havoc](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/bloodlines/bloodline-mutations/blood-havoc/)
>
> This ability replaces the **sorcerer’s 1st-level** bloodline power or the bloodrager’s 4th-level bloodline power.
>
> [Blood Intensity](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/bloodlines/bloodline-mutations/blood-intensity/)
>
> This ability replaces the **sorcerer’s 3rd-level** bloodline power or the bloodrager’s 8th-level bloodline power.
>
> [Blood Piercing](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/bloodlines/bloodline-mutations/blood-piercing/)
>
> This ability replaces the **sorcerer’s 9th-level** bloodline power or the bloodrager’s 4th-level bloodline power.

So, while the bloodline mutation rule certainly would allow for a mutations, in general, to replace a lower level power, the published mutations do not. This has been [confirmed](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2topa?Bloodline-Mutations#6) by the author, [Alexander Augunas](http://paizo.com/people/AlexanderAugunas), as well:

> When I wrote bloodline mutations, I intended you to swap what I listed as a swappable power. If you don't want to swap that power, take it as a feat.

This means that your only option is to replace one of the **bloodline bonus feats** gained *at least* at the level of the bloodline mutation you want to obtain, at 13th level, for instance.

Comment: Thanks, I was a bit confused if the original text was in conflict with that bit in each mutation's wording, so a case of specific vs specific, but as you pointed out, it was actually only general vs specific.